# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint/ Erro ao add chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela chamada `Disciplina`, entretanto não estou conseguindo por conta das chaves estrangeiras. Já revisei várias vezes e não consigo identificar o erro, se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

```
CREATE TABLE `Curso` (
  `idCurso` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nomeCurso` VARCHAR(45),
  `tipoCurso` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCurso`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `Matriz` (
  `Curso_idCurso` INT NOT NULL,
  `anoInicio` INT NOT NULL,
  `anoFim` INT NOT NULL,
  `status` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `tituloMatriz` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Disciplina_codDisciplina` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Curso_idCurso`, `anoInicio`),
  INDEX `fk_Matriz_Curso1_idx` (`Curso_idCurso` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Matriz_Curso1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Curso_idCurso`)
  REFERENCES `Curso` (`idCurso`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `Disciplina` (
  `codDisciplina` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `corrente` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `Matriz_anoInicio` INT NOT NULL,
  `Matriz_idCurso` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codDisciplina`, `Matriz_anoInicio`,`Matriz_idCurso`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Matriz_idCurso`) 
      REFERENCES `Matriz` (`Curso_idCurso`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Matriz_anoInicio`)
      REFERENCES `Matriz` (`anoInicio`))    
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na tabela `Matriz` você está declarando como chave primária a composição de `Curso_idCurso` e `anoInicio`. Já na tabela `Disciplina` você está tentando criar uma referência a partir de somente `Matriz_idCurso`. A declaração de referência deveria incluir todos os campos da chave da tabela pai.

Assim:

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (`Matriz_idCurso`,`Matriz_anoInicio`) 
      REFERENCES `Matriz` (`Curso_idCurso`, `anoInicio`)
...
```

Particularmente eu abandonei o uso de chaves compostas há anos. Na prática seu uso só gera mais trabalho, principalmente quando se usa um mapeamento objeto relacional.